# SSRS 2012 Merge multiple values into 1 row

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am trying to  do the following :

1. I have a column called "Velocity" which has values like "Excess", "Active", "Slow". (Fig 1)
2. For these values (Excess, Slow etc) I want to have a column with these names in a new table and the values for these columns to be a total. So for Market- W100 Seattle total of how many Excess in the "Excess" column. (Fig 2)

[Fig 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uregO.png)

[Fig 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OwT9.png)

I created a column with these names using the calculated field but not sure how to add a query for this. Any suggestions on how I can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert a tablix into your report.  Then create a row group on Fields!Market.value and a column group on Fields! Velocity.value.  Then in the body you can just put an expression like =COUNT(Fields!Velocity.value).